# Ruby unable to create directories

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to read a file having string values, line by line and create respective folder/directory for every string value.

```
#require 'fileutils'

value=File.open('D:\\exercise\\list.txt').read
value.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")
value.each_line do |line|
    line.chomp
    print "FOlder names:#{line}"
    Dir.mkdir("D:\\exercise\\#{line}")
end
```

and I'm getting the below error:

```
read_folders_svn.rb:8:in `mkdir': Invalid argument - Australia (Errno::EINVAL)
        from read_folders_svn.rb:8:in `block in <main>'
```

list.txt file's content below

```
Australia
USA
EUrope
Africa
ANtartica
```

I tried printing the values and its working fine, while creating the respective directories facing the above issue and even tried using fileutils (fileutils.mkdir) option but still the same issue.

Any suggestions please. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the script has the permission to create dirs?

Comment: on windows, this should not be problem -))

Comment: @marmeladze Windows provides more sophisticate access rights than Unix-based systems. It uses ACLs and inheritable rights. That *could* be a problem in general but, most probably, it is not the problem here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in the line:

```
line.chomp
```

It strips the newline from the tail of `line` and returns a value that is ignored. It doesn't change the value of `line`. It still ends with `"\n"` and this is a character that is not allowed in file names on Windows. The code runs fine on Linux and creates directories whose names end in `"\n"`.

The solution is also simple. Use [`#chomp!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-chomp-21) instead:

```
#require 'fileutils'

value=File.open('D:\\exercise\\list.txt').read
value.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")
value.each_line do |line|
    line.chomp!
    print "FOlder names:#{line}"
    Dir.mkdir("D:\\exercise\\#{line}")
end
```

*(It might still produce errors, however, because of empty lines in the input).*

Comment: It's always a good idea to do things like `p line` when confused as to what's going wrong. That would've shown `"Australia\n"` here.

Comment: @axiac : Thanks for pointing out the error. +1 for the chomp!

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked that the line doesn't contain extra characters? Where `line.chomp!` will solve your problem but `line.strip!` is probably the more robust variant, esp if you have windows line-endings of \r\n.

Difference between `chomp` and `strip`

> String#chomp operates on the end of strings, while String#strip
>   operates on the start and end of strings. String#chomp takes an
>   optional 'record separator' argument, while String#strip takes no
>   arguments. If String#chomp is given no arguments it will remove
>   carriage returns characters from the end of the string being operated
>   on (\r, \n or \r\n). If String#chomp is passed a string as an
>   argument, that string is removed from the end of the string being
>   operated on. String#strip will remove leading and trailing null and
>   whitespace characters from the string being operated on.

`"Cadel Evans".chomp(' Evans') # => "Cadel"`

`"Cadel Evans\r\n".chomp # => "Cadel Evans"`

`"\tRobbie McEwen\r\n".strip # => "Robbie McEwen"`

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution , much appreciated.